# Chrome, even in incognito won't refresh with new changes to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I'm growing frustrated with the whole mix of Spring Tool Suite, Tomcat and Chrome.  I'm working on a website's back end and I'm having all sorts of troubles getting my webpage to reload properly when I make changes to the JavaScript.  I've made a fix to a problem in my code and when I go to preview, the error is still there.  When I inspect the JavaScript in the Chrome Dev Tools, I see that it is *still* loading the JavaScript before I made the change, despite me having saved the file.  I've rebooted Tomcat, I've been using Incognito mode, I've been deleting my cache and yet even in incognito, Chrome won't dump the old JavaScript file for the new one.

It's getting frustrating, because I waste time with every change I make with the JavaScript trying to wrestle with Chrome and Tomcat to get my webpage to use the most recent saved version of my JavaScript.  I don't know if this matters, but I'm not writing my JavaScript in STS with Tomcat and my Java code, but it is in the same folder as my project and when I open it in STS, it always has my most recent save changes anyways.

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: If you see the old even after restarting your server then try going to the network tab in chrome and selecting disable cache

Comment: We could take a closer look, if you want us to, for sure. Would be great if you could explain the exact setting, attach a sample project, describe steps how to reproduce, etc. Since I am working with Spring Boot projects most of the time, my setup is usually a bit different than yours, but we can try to help nevertheless.